# Schedule a task that runs every x milliseconds

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

As part of my schoolwork, I'm trying to write a java method that schedule a task that runs every x milliseconds

> public ScheduledTask scheduleEvery(long time, Runnable task)

where the first time it's executed is when another method fire(long time) is called. For example:

1. time = 2001
2. Submit scheduler.every(1000, runnable);
3. fire(2345) -> runnable is executed -> scheduled at 3345
4. fire(3123) -> noting happens
5. fire(4566) -> runnable is executed once -> scheduled to 5566
   ....

I'm thinking of creating a list to store these tasks. When fire() is called they will be executed, removed from the list and rescheduled after x milliseconds. Can anyone let me know if this is possible?

Comment: If you really want to do this (and it's not a homework to write your own) then use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Sadly this is indeed my hw and I have to build it from scratch

Comment: Could you elaborate why nothing should happen at `fire(3123)`? Is that because there's already a scheduled task? Why would `fire(2345)` cause a rescheduling since there'd be a task scheduled for 3001 already? Is that because the task would alrady have run once?

Comment: A task is executed the first time when fire() is called, in this case it's 2345 and because of the nature of my (not yet coded) scheduleEvery(), it is scheduled to 2345+1000=3345. Since 3345>3123, nothing happens at fire(3123) etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it ...

```
Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Call the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method after the fire() method has been called if and only if it has not been called before. You can store this info in a `isFired` variable in your class.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without ScheduledExecutorService? Is it possible to use the linkedlist of events like I said?

Comment: Yeah, you can just save the runnable and the delay inside the class.
Then you can use Thread.sleep(delay) method in the loop to periodically and then call runnable.run() each time it wakes up